# PHP WkHtmlToPdf cant add multiple pages

Tags: php, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I am having problems adding multiple pages to a PDF document using the great PHP wkHTMLToPdf wrapper.

The following code just gives me a blank page

```
require_once('phpwkhtmltopdf/WkHtmlToPdf.php');
$pdf = new WkHtmlToPdf;

$pdf->addPage('http://www.google.co.uk');
$pdf->addPage('http://www.google.co.uk');

$pdf->send('test.pdf');
exit();
```

but this works fine.

```
require_once('phpwkhtmltopdf/WkHtmlToPdf.php');
$pdf = new WkHtmlToPdf;

$pdf->addPage('http://www.google.co.uk');

$pdf->send('test.pdf');
exit();
```

Comment: Does send return true? Check with something like `if (!$pdf->send()) { die($pdf->getError()); }`. The `getError()` function can be useful to check even if it does return true though, maybe it might contain a warning or at least some info. The wrapper code is fairly easy to "debug" by adding `die()` statements and echos and stuff. Also, try `getCommand($filename)` and check if the command syntax is correct, maybe try to run it in a standalone command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because I had used apt-get install to install wkhtmltopdf but doing this provides a very limited solution i.e. a number of options are omitted including adding more than one page. By downloading and installing manually everything worked.